# How to pass selected values from multiple select html (Chosen.js) element to c#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I want to pass selected values from . My code returns nothing is selected. 

In .aspx

```
<script>
    $('#<%=serialNumberDDL.ClientID %>').chosen();
</script>

<select runat="server" id="serialNumberDDL" name="serialNumberDDL" class="form-control" data-placeholder="select serial number" multiple="true"></select>
```

In .aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    serialNumberDDL.DataTextField = "serialNumber";
    serialNumberDDL.DataValueField = "serialNumber";
    List<SerialNumberJson> temp = LeaseBLL.getAllSerialNumbers();
    serialNumberDDL.DataSource = temp;
    serialNumberDDL.DataBind();
}
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string temp = serialNumberDDL.Value; //temp returns null

    List<string> serialNumbers = new List<string>();
    foreach (ListItem li in serialNumberDDL.Items)
    {
        if (li.Selected == true) //always false
        {
            serialNumbers.Add(li.Value);
        }
    }
```

But when I write out the values using javascript `$('#<%=serialNumberDDL.ClientID %>').val()`, it shows the selected values.

Why are selected values not passed to C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BEcause this plug in works on Client Side not Server Side. Try to use `HiddenField` Control to save the selected data. and use this `HiddenField.Value` to retrive the selected data.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function CopySelectedData(){
       $('#<%=hiddenField.ClientID %>').val($('#<%=serialNumberDDL.ClientID %>').val())
       return true;
    }
</script>

<asp:Button ID="btn_Click" runat-"server" OnClientClick="return CopySelectedData()"></asp:Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your js code runs before the select tag even loaded. Try in the document ready event.